# Matplotlib scatter plot is bunching up in the middle of the graphic

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7

I'm trying to plot some temperature data overtime.  I'm setting up the scatter plot similar to what I do with a line plot but the scatter plot bunches up all the data in the vertical center of the graphic.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried plotting simple data it at works ok, when I try using my data the plot bunches up.

This is my code

```py
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

path="./temps.csv"
file = open(path,newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(reader)
dates = []
temps  = []
fl_dates=[]
for row in reader:
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    dates.append(date)
    temps.append(float(row[1]))
numrows=len(dates)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
fl_dates.append(dates[0])
fl_dates.append(dates[numrows-1])
ax.set_xticks(fl_dates)
plt.title("Temperatures Over Time")
plt.scatter(dates,temps)
plt.ylabel('Temperatues')
plt.xlabel('Date/Time')
plt.xticks(rotation='45')
plt.tight_layout();
plt.savefig('temps.png')
plt.show()
```

[Result of Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7oSm.png)

This is some sample  data that is read in from "./temps.csv"

08/30/2019 12:03:33,31.000000 
08/30/2019 12:03:43,34.000000 
08/30/2019 12:03:54,33.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:04,32.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:15,31.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:25,30.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:36,31.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:46,32.000000 
08/30/2019 12:04:57,35.000000 
08/30/2019 12:05:07,36.000000 
08/30/2019 12:05:18,37.000000 
08/30/2019 12:05:28,30.000000 
08/30/2019 12:05:39,31.000000 
08/30/2019 12:05:50,33.000000 
08/30/2019 12:06:00,32.000000 
08/30/2019 12:06:11,31.000000 
08/30/2019 12:06:21,32.000000 
08/30/2019 12:06:32,35.000000 
08/30/2019 12:06:42,31.000000

This  what's plotted:

[scatter plot with data bunched up in middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7oSm.png)

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. But for date scatters you will need to set the limits manually (`plt.xlim(...)`). Though it seems that here you can use a normal plot, like `plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", linestyle="none")` in which case autoscaling works better. From next matplotlib version onwards, scatter will also autoscale correctly.

Comment: What do I set the xlim to? I when I do right, left=plt.xlim() I get 0.0, 737301.5046527778.

Comment: If the data is sorted, would `plt.xlim(dates[0], dates[-1])` not work?

Comment: Plt.xlim(dates[0], dates[len(dates)-1] worked.  Didn’t know what to use.